# Problems with Sympy Sum()

Tags: python, sympy

I'm trying to derive the CDF of a discrete distribution whose PMF is given by:

```
P(d)=log_10(1+1/d) for d=1,...,9
```

Here's my code to derive the CDF:

```
import sympy

#Find the CDF
d=sympy.Symbol('d')
pmf=sympy.log((1+1/d),10)
CDF=sympy.Sum(pmf,(d,1,d))
print(CDF)
#compute the CDF
CDF=CDF.doit()
print(CDF)
#simplify the expression
CDF=CDF.simplify()
print(CDF)
```

This doesn't evaluate--it just prints out the sum:

```
Sum(log(1 + 1/d)/log(10), (d, 1, d))
Sum(log(1 + 1/d)/log(10), (d, 1, d))
Sum(log(1 + 1/d), (d, 1, d))/log(10)
```

What am I doing incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong. This should work:

```
In [83]: d = Symbol('d')                                                                                                                       

In [84]: CDF = Sum(log(1 + 1/d)/log(10), (d, 1, d))                                                                                            

In [85]: CDF                                                                                                                                   
Out[85]: 
  d             
_____           
╲               
 ╲              
  ╲      ⎛    1⎞
   ╲  log⎜1 + ─⎟
   ╱     ⎝    d⎠
  ╱   ──────────
 ╱     log(10)  
╱               
‾‾‾‾‾           
d = 1           

In [86]: CDF.doit()                                                                                                                            
Out[86]: 
  d             
_____           
╲               
 ╲              
  ╲      ⎛    1⎞
   ╲  log⎜1 + ─⎟
   ╱     ⎝    d⎠
  ╱   ──────────
 ╱     log(10)  
╱               
‾‾‾‾‾           
d = 1
```

It doesn't because `Sum` just doesn't know how to evaluate this particular summation. You can substitute for `d` to get a result for a sum without symbolic limit:

```
In [88]: CDF.subs(d, 5).doit()                                                                                                                 
Out[88]: 
log(6/5) + log(5/4) + log(4/3) + log(3/2) + log(2)
──────────────────────────────────────────────────
                     log(10)
```

To get a symbolic result we can convert the `Sum` to a `Product` and have that `doit` which works. It should be possible to do `CDF.rewrite(Product)` but that isn't implemented so here's a roundabout way of converting the `Sum` to a `Product` (using `exp.expand`) to evaluate the result:

```
In [95]: log(exp(CDF).expand().doit()).simplify()                                                                                              
Out[95]: 
log(d + 1)
──────────
 log(10)
```